# Stat with find not excluding files

Tags: linux, bash

Within a bash script, I am trying to find files based on their octet using stat in combination with find, however I want to skip some files (file1, file2, etc.).  However this doesn't appear to be working.  Why is this and how I can fix it?  Is this the best way of doing this?

```
$(stat --format %a 2>&1 $(find /example/dir -type f -not \( -name 'file1' -o \
       -name 'file2' -o -name 'file3' -o -name 'file4' \) -prune) | egrep "777|755"
```

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: Hey - not fair changing the question materially (by using `egrep '777|775'`) and out of sight (on the far right of a grotesquely over-long single line) without commenting that you're doing so.  Play fair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original question — 777 permission only

If you are looking for files with 777 permission, use `find` to do that:

```
find /example/dir -type f -perm 777
```

If you don't want to include `file1`, `file2`, `file3` or `file4` in the output, use `grep` too:

```
find /example/dir -type f -perm 777 | grep -Ev 'file[1234]'
```

If you want the output from `stat` for those files, then:

```
find /example/dir -type f -perm 777 | grep -Ev 'file[1234]' | xargs stat --format %a
```

or:

```
stat --format %a $(find /example/dir -type f -perm 777 | grep -Ev 'file[1234]')
```

This is more likely to run into problems if the list of files is huge.  You can reinstate the `-prune` option on any of the `find` commands as you require.  However, running `find example/dir -type f` and `find example/dir -type f -prune` made no difference to the result I saw.

#### Revised question — 777 and 775 permission

If you're looking for 777 or 775 permission, then you need:

```
find /example/dir -type f -perm +775
```

This happens to work because there's only one bit different between the 777 and 775 permissions.  A more general and extensible solution would use `-or` operations:

```
find /example/dir -type f \( -perm 777 -or -perm 775 \)
```

With changes in the numbers, this could look for 664 or 646 permission without picking up executable files, which `-perm +622` would pick up.

#### Problems in the question code

As to what is going wrong with the code in the question — I am not completely sure.

```
$ find example/dir -type f
example/dir/a/filea
example/dir/a/fileb
example/dir/b/filea
example/dir/b/fileb
example/dir/c/filea
example/dir/c/fileb
example/dir/filea
example/dir/fileb
$ find example/dir -type f -not \( -name filea -o -name fileb \)
$ find example/dir -type f -not \( -name filea -or -name fileb \)
$ find example/dir -type f \( -name filea -or -name fileb \)
example/dir/a/filea
example/dir/a/fileb
example/dir/b/filea
example/dir/b/fileb
example/dir/c/filea
example/dir/c/fileb
example/dir/filea
example/dir/fileb
$ find example/dir -type f ! \( -name filea -or -name fileb \)
$ find example/dir -type f \( -not -name filea -and -not -name fileb \)
$
```

The `-not` or `!` operator seems to completely mess things up, which I'd not expect.  Superficially, this looks like a bug, but I'd have to have a lot more evidence and have to do a lot of very careful scrutiny of the `find` specification before I claimed 'bug'.

This testing was done with the `find` on Mac OS X 10.8.3 (BSD), no GNU `find`.

(Your use of the term *'octet'* in the question is puzzling; it is normally used to indicate a byte in network communications, with the more stringent meaning that it is precisely 8 bits which a byte need not be.  The permissions are presented in octal and are based on 16 bits, 2 octets, in the inode.)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.  I meant octal not octet.  The -not operator was confusing me; the results were misleading. You have helped me a great deal, a very lengthy response :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-perm` option to check permissions, in combination with checking filenames.

```
find /example/dir -type f -not \( -name 'file1' -o -name 'file2' -o -name 'file3' -o -name 'file4' \) -perm 777
```

You don't need `-prune`. This is used to prevent descending until certain subdirectories, it doesn't do anything with files. And it applies to directories that *match* the specification, so using it with `-not` in your case would be the opposite of what you wanted.